# If $G$ is a graph with at least one cut-vertex, then at least $2$ of the blocks of $G$ contain exactly $1$ cut-vertex

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

If $G$ is a graph with at least one cut-vertex, then at least $2$ of the blocks of $G$ contain exactly $1$ cut-vertex.

To illustrate, I have this example:

[image]

A simpler example would be to consider two cycles with a common vertex, we can see that it is a cutting vertex and has only two blocks, since each pair of vertices is in a common cycle.

Comment: I have an idea, but have not made it completely formal. From $G$ build a graph whose vertices are blocks *and* cutting vertices and whose edges connect a block to the cutting vertices it contains. This graph should be acyclic. An extremal point is a block with exactly one cutting vertex and there must be at least to extremal points.

Comment: @MatthewDaly It looks similar. Would it be another way to approach the problem?